# Sublime Text 3: Error trying to parse settings, colons highlighted

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

(English is not my native language so there might be mistakes here:)

I was trying to change the visual style of Sublime Text 3, I installed the "https://github.com/kkga/spacegray" but were stopped by an error. This was not the first time and have got this message before:

Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings:19:1

[image: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings:19:1]

As you can see it highlights the colon but can't fix it either way, every setting above the style are not in use now because it only accepts (and activates the style) if I cut out everything else like this:

[image: Cut out everything else]

I tried changing characters and finding answers for this problem but have been unsuccessful until now. My settings

Comment: you're missing a comma there in line 18, after `word wrap: false`. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @cnluzon you should consider posting this as an answer because it definitely is the correct solution.

Comment: @Peh thanks, just added it :)

Comment: Whenever you have a parsing error in json, the error most usually appeared in the line immediately above it. The missing comma here is the culprit

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you are missing a comma there in line 18, it should be:

```
"word wrap": false,
```

That's why you get the parsing error, after each option there must be either a comma, indicating that there are more config parameters remaining, or a closing bracket `}`.

When adding new settings, make sure that all of them are separated by commas.